# Почему не работает валидация через ajax?

Tags: ajax, yii2, валидация

При включенной клиентской валидации работает всё отлично, но как только я её отключаю и включаю валидацию через Ajax, всё перестаёт работать и постоянно вылетает ошибка о том что поле не заполнено. Хотя оно, естественно, заполнено.
**Вьюха**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'enableClientValidation' => false,
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            ]);?>
            <?=$form->field($model, 'name')->label('Full Name')?>
            <?=$form->field($model, 'email')->label('Email Address')?>
            <?=$form->field($model, 'subject')->label('Subject')?>
            <?=$form->field($model, 'body')->label('Message')->textarea(['rows' => 6])?>
            <?=$form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(),[
                'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
            ]);?>
            <?=Html::submitButton('Send Message', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])?>
            <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

**Контроллер**

```
public function actionContact(){
    $model = new ContactForm();

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->isPost){
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
        Common::sendMail($model->email, $model->subject, $model->body, 'Name');
    }
    return $this->render('contact',[
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**Модель (правила)**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'required'],

        ['email', 'email'],

        ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: А какое поле не проходит валидацию?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка нашлась сама.

В контроллере нужно написать вот так:

`if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->isPost){
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()){
           Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
           return ActiveForm::validate($model);
      }
    }`